# Showing elements on click in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, onclick

I have a page that is supposed to show good answers after someone clicks on the button "i want to see the answers".

I made an icon that displays next to correct answers:

```
  <% if answer.correct == true %>
    <%= raw @ikona %><p> <%= answer.content %></p>
  <% else %>
  <p><%= answer.content %></p>
      <% end %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

I want to display it only after the user clicks on the button. It can't make the page reload, because user should be able to compare things they ticked as correct with actual correct answer. How do I go about it?

Comment: If you are loading all content then you can initial hide it and show it on click of icon using simple jquery hide/show event

Comment: you can not doing this by Ruby, this is client side logic and need implement on Javascript.[Read doc](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: as @Icicle says you would best use jquery for this.  Ryan Bate's railscasts talks about using jquery in rails... http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Front End**

What you're asking is to do with the `front-end` vs `back-end` of a Rails app

Front-end GUI functionality is not what Rails is for - Rails is a back-end system to take `requests` and process a `response`

Therefore, to answer your question, you'll basically need to use `jquery` on the front-end to expose the content you want `.on("click"`. The question arises about *how* you want that content to be displayed (can use Ajax)

---

**JQuery**

Javascript is client-side (it loads in the browser), and affects the DOM (Document Object Model). This means that every HTML element on your page can be affected / manipulated by Javascript - allowing you to create "interactivity" on the page

For your "click" requirement, you can do this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#element", function(){
   // do something here
});
```

This *binds* the `click` event of your DOM to the functionality you wish to perform, which will basically mean loading your `div`

**Please note that I have used [Javascript delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) above, as Rails will typically prevent standard javascript from working (turbolinks causes so many issues)

---

**Data**

Once you've implemented your `click` event bind in your javascript, you need functionality to make it do something useful. The two options you have are:

> 1. Ajax (pull data dynamically)
> 2. Hidden DIV

--

**DIV**

Basically, if you want to cause content to show when you click your button, you will need to call that content from somewhere. The easiest way is to use a hidden div, as below:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.hidden { display: none; }

#app/assets/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<div class="hidden" id="your_id">
   Hidden content
</div>
```

This will allow you to then use something like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", function() {
   $("#your_id").show();
});
```

--

**Ajax**

An alternative will be to use `ajax` to pull the data you need:

```
#app/controllers/controller.rb
respond_to :json, :js, :html


#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#element", function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "answers/" + $(this).attr("id")
       success: function(data) {
           // append data to your DOM
       }
    });
});
```